# underscore template with require js text plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

So I've this template in a html file -

```
<%=  x %>
```

And in one of my view, it's been loaded with help of requirejs. I want to load this template with data.

```
var template = _.template(this.rawTpl);
var data = { x: 10};
this.$('.instant_preview').html(template(data));
```

But this throws

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

`console.log(this.rawTpl);` shows that templates been loaded. Whats the problem here?

Comment: Is your answer is in the error... Where have you defined x?

Comment: @SebastianTroy it's loading template with data. So `x` is being passed via `template` method.

Comment: In this line `var data = { x: 10};` how does it know that `x` is part of the template and not an undefined local variable?

Comment: Does error disappear when replace ```_.template(this.rawTpl);``` by ```_.template("<%= x %>");```?

Comment: @PavelKomiagin No sadly it does not.

Comment: @SebastianTroy error is thrown in template not in script code.

Comment: There's something missing in your question, it should work with what you describe. See http://jsfiddle.net/tphqtry2/ Random guess : you load your data asynchronously

Comment: @nikoshr Indeed. The issue was with overridden **variable templatesetting**. I should have be using `qa.x` instead.